# Were there other literary topics that were covered by the Inklings?

Tags: j-r-r-tolkien, cs-lewis

I have read that J.R.R. Tolkien's Númenórean legend in the form of *The Lost Road* and the *Out of the Silent Planet* series by C.S. Lewis took shape from deciding on topics in their writing group, the Inklings.

Tolkien's topic was time travel, and Lewis' topic was space travel.

Were any of the other members involved with topics, and if so, were there any other literary contributions that came of them?

Comment: The Inklings were pretty much a group of friends meeting to discuss literature in general and their writing in particular. As such it's likely that everybody discussed much of what they were working on at the time. I believe you will find it hard to separate 'Inkling projects' out from everything else that the members were working on at the time.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that *The Lost Road*, and *Out of the Silent Planet* came out of a joint project between Lewis and Tolkien. Their idea was to write thrillers, but with mythic qualities. They called it mythopoeic. I don't think that it was an Inkling project, but it's of course possible that some of the Inklings were involved in the meetings discussing the stories as they were being written.